# Factory Girl not destroying objects properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am creating an object with several has_many associations. Everything with regards tob building the object works fine, but when I try to test the deletion of one of the children or parent, it does not reflect in the test.

For example:

```
 base_article = Factory(:base_article, :articles => [Factory(:article)])
 p base_article.articles.size
 base_article.articles.first.destroy
 p base_article.articles.size
 base_article.destroyed?.should == true
```

This prints out:

1

1

I am testing the callback after destroy on the article that deletes the base when there are no more children. Why is the size of the articles association not being reduced by one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reload the articles collection as Rails' database caching is stale:

```
base_article = Factory(:base_article, :articles => [Factory(:article)])
base_article.articles.size # => 1

base_article.articles.first.destroy
base_article.articles.size # => 1
base_article.articles.reload.size # => 0

base_article.destroyed?.should == true
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I realized that reloading works, but is there anyway around that? It seems like a hack, no?

Comment: It does seem a bit hacky, I agree, but it's worth putting up with in tests/specs for the speedup it gives in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

You could used articles.count instead. 'Size' gives you the length of the in-memory collection. Count does a query and gets the latest total from the db.